# Can I later install ssis, ssrs and ssas services in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server-2016

Please tell me how to install SQL Server 2016 and can I install MSBI Tools (SSAS, SSRS, SSIS) later?

Comment: Yes, you can change list of installed components later.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following video to install SQL server 2016

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gfmk1ZbunUI

Use the following link to download SSRS

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55252&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True

You can use MSBI tools anytime, those are not related with sql server first time setup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can install SQL server as a standalone first, and rest of the BI components laters.

You can install SQL server 2016 by following the below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-installation-wizard-setup?view=sql-server-ver15